# UIImage won't display PNG with white foreground patterns

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, xcode9-beta

Really need some help here. I'm doing something really basic, I have a `UIButton` and set its image to a `UIImage` I created. The image file is PNG with transparent background and a white foreground (the actual pattern). However, the `UIImage` doesn't seem to work. Here's some screenshots as reference.

this is how I set up the button:

```
    let exitButton = UIButton()
    exitButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "success"), for: .normal)
    exitButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 56, height: 56)
    exitButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Other images seems to work..

this is the image I'm using, it doesn't work
[image: image that doesn't work]
this is the image I tested, and it works
[image: this kind images words properly]

only difference is the foreground color...

Comment: Try making your X black. I think by default UIButton images are set as Template and tinted based on some formula.

Comment: I does seem to work, but why..can't I use a white X in anyway. Thanks by the way.

Comment: You can subclass the UIButton to have it not set the image to be Template. But, using template, you can just use the .TintColor property to change the color to whatever you need. It's the same thing that happens to tabbarbuttonitems.

Answer (score 0):

Template images (the default mode for UIButton images) take the alpha and basically represent the rest as a tinted mask. For whatever reason, white is not treated correctly in the process. The way I think about it is you are giving the button a mask to work with, so all of the images I give to default buttons are black with transparency.

However, you can subclass UIButton and use whatever image you would like:

```
    class buttonClose: UIButton {
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            if self.image(for: .normal) != nil {
                let g:UIImage = UIImage(named: "close_button32")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            let p:UIImage = UIImage(named: "close_button32highlighted")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

                self.setImage(g, for: .normal)
                self.setImage(p, for: .selected)
                self.backgroundColor = .red
            }
        }
    }
```